# automatic uv packing using uvpackmaster2

Tags: python, scripting, uv

We want to use [uvpackmaster2](https://uvpackmaster.com/) to pack the uv maps of our meshes. The main goal is to bake all materials into one texture. When calling the uv-packing algorithm, i am getting an error that the mesh should be in edit mode but actually i set all meshes to editmode before. Here is my code:

```
#preprocessing
for object in bpy.data.objects:
    wm_copy = object.matrix_world.copy()
    object.parent = None
    object.matrix_world = wm_copy

for object in [object for object in bpy.data.objects if object.type!= "MESH"]:
    bpy.data.objects.remove(object)

#uv packing
for mesh in bpy.data.objects:
    mesh.data.uv_layers.active = mesh.data.uv_layers.new(name="bake")

bpy.context.scene.uvp2_props.margin = 0.005
bpy.context.scene.uvp2_props.precision = 500
bpy.context.scene.uvp2_props.pixel_margin = 10
bpy.context.scene.uvp2_props.pixel_margin_tex_size = 1024

bpy.context.area.type = 'VIEW_3D'
for object in bpy.data.objects: object.select_set(True)
bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')
bpy.ops.uvpackmaster2.uv_pack()
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='DESELECT')
bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
for object in bpy.data.objects: object.select_set(False)
```

The operator does a few steps:

Topology Analysis

[image]

Packing Process

[image]

And all of this takes some time. And i guess the packing is done. But at the very end i get this error (and i do not get my desired new uv map):
[image]

I think my code works finde. I can, for example, replace the uvpackmaster method with **bpy.ops.uv.smart_project()** and the code does what it should do.

You may want to look at the uvpackmaster [code](https://uvpackmaster.com/downloads/).

TL;DR:
So i guess i have to questions:

- Any experience with scripting uvpackmaster2 addon?
- Any experience with this speciffic error?

Comment: The last error states that you should be in edit mode while running this specific operator

Comment: Sorry if i didn't make that clear - i did read the error. But i don't know what i should do with it. In my code i do switch to edit mode before calling the operator.

Comment: I found out why the error occurs. The call bpy.ops.uvpackmaster2.uv_pack() is asynchronous, which means, that the code after that runs immediately and does not wait for the packing to finish. That way the mesh is set to objectmode before uvpackmaster ist done with packing.